# Why is double slit considered am example of superposition when it's just showing wave nature of particles?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, double-slit-experiment, interference, superposition

When electrons are individually passed through two slits, the wave function of each electron, after passing through the slits, combine to form an interference pattern.

Isn't this just a demonstration of the wave nature of electrons rather than superposition?

Since the wave pattern represent a single state of the electron, we can't say that the electron is in many superimposed states.

If we use "state" in the sense of a single defined position or momentum, just like in the classical sense, then only we can say that the wave nature of electron represents a superposition of multiple states, but that's not how we define state in quantum mechanics, no?

Comment: *"Since the wave pattern represent a single state of the electron, we can't say that the electron is in many superimposed states."* Every quantum state is "a single state", so by your reasoning we wouldn't ever call any state a "superposition".

Comment: @DanielSank No it should not be called a  superposition because it can be explained one particle at a time.

Comment: Individual electrons or photons only go through one slit at a time ￼

Answer (score 1):

> Isn't this just a demonstration of the wave nature of electrons rather than superposition?

That's a semantic thing. You can say it with different words, and the important thing is that people understand what you're talking about when you say it. You can say this one either way and people will generally get the idea.

What's important is the actual events that the words describe.

We know that when an atom emits a photon, it releases a single particle with a defined amount of energy, that travels until it is absorbed by another atom. The second atom absorbs exactly the same amount of energy, the whole photon.

It isn't that atoms can collect energy in various ways that leave them variously ready to get a little bit more from light waves and get tipped over into a different state. It isn't that a collection of atoms are statistically varied in their responsiveness to weak radiation. We know beyond any doubt that atoms emit whole photons and the energy that one atom emits is the same energy that another atom absorbs.

So if a photon is like a point that travels from the emitter to the detector, it makes sense that it has to pass through one slit or the other. How can it be affected by a second slit that we know beyond any doubt that it doesn't interact with? It takes a whole lot of theory to explain that.

Similarly with electrons. Put a whole lot of detectors behind the two slits. We know that each electron can be detected by only one detector. And each detector either detects an electron or it's entirely unaffected by it. You can never have one electron that sort of charges up a detector to make a later electron more likely to set it off. This is definitely certain, there is no possibility of any interaction. Therefore, each electron must be affected by both slits and not just the one it travels through. Maybe it travels like a wave before it gives all its energy to precisely one detector in one place.

If we could tell a 19th-century physicist about this experiment, he would certainly say that each electron travels as a wave, and interacts with an atom as a particle in one single place. It would seem like there is no other possibility. But today's physicists are sometimes more inventive and sometimes more like engineers. So for example there can be phonons that travel from one slit to the other and affect the particles that travel through either one. Or we can say that we have math which correctly describes the results, and we don't need any explanations how things work beyond the equations that are correct.

So you can wave your hands and come up with ways to talk about the energy which in some contexts is spread out everywhere, and in other contexts is concentrated entirely at one atom where it is absorbed. It won't make sense but you can try. Or you can say that it isn't the energy which is the waves but it's probability waves, and that doesn't really make any sense either. But some people will be satisfied to hear it. Or you can just say that it doesn't need to make sense, it just is.

The important thing though is that we know beyond dispute, with no possible quibble, that the single photons or electrons are created independently with no possible correlation, and travel independently, and are absorbed independently with no correlations. That's what makes it interesting, and if it wasn't true then the question would not be very interesting. But it is known to be true, and nobody has any right to doubt it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you studied the double slit experiment one electron at a time?

[Here are the data:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment#Interference_of_individual_particles)

[image: dblslit]

> electron build up over time.

Each dot on frame **a** ( and all other frames) is the footprint if a single electron. It has an (x,y) and a z the distance of the screen to the slits.

**It is a dot** within the measurement errors of the screen There is no interference pattern, nothing spread all over the place, as a wave would be.

**The accumulation** of a large number of electrons going through the same boundary conditions shows the interference pattern which is modeled by quantum mechanics  with  $Ψ^*Ψ$ the complex conjugate squared of the wavefunction describing the experiment "electron of fixed momentum scattering through two slits which are  a given distance apart and at a given width" .

> Since the wave pattern represent a single state of the electron, we can't say that the electron is in many superimposed states.

Wrong , the wave pattern appears with the accumulation of many electrons with the same boundary conditions. There is no superposition because each goes through one at a time.

Comment: Just curious, on the regions of destructive interference for single particle interference, was there previously more particles incoming, for the same amount of time in a single slit opening? Did opening two slits, actually decrease the number of particles arriving at the 'dark bands' or do we infer statistical nature from the "pattern" we are seeing here?

Comment: "*there is no superposition*" - Even when a single electron is eventually going to hit a particular place on the screen, it is still described as a wave function of superimposed states.

Comment: @Daud The wave function is a mathematical function obeying a wave equation, and a wavepacket solution for describing the electron approaching the screen will have many frequencies true, but it is not a thing that can be measured and fitted. What can be measured is the complex conjugate square and it needs an accumulation of electrons to get the probability curve that shows the wave nature in interference patterns.

Comment: @Weezy single slits are another boundary condition problem, a different wavefunction and its complex conjugate squared. which shows the pattern.

Comment: @Daud you don’t need the wave function, besides it can’t explain anything physically. A single electron or a single photon remains a single particles from source to detection screen traveling through only one slit.

Comment: @Weezy Opening two slits definitely decreases the number of particles arriving at the "dark bands" . They would not be "dark" if it was not so !

Answer (score 0):

Remember that a superposition simply means that the wave-function of an electron is expressed as an expansion in terms of some set of functions. In that sense, every wave-function is a superposition, since all wave-functions can be expanded over other basis sets.

Answer (score 0):

So an electron even before emission is already interacting with the EM field (virtual forces) .... we can say that the electron is considering many paths and that certain paths are more probable ... hence the pattern.  This is the essence of Feynman's path integral.

So we can have many superpositions of all the electron fields of the entire apparatus which eventually influence to which peak (not trough) the electron will go to.  All happening in the dynamic EM field ... while the electron is in an excited state (not emitted yet).

There is really no mystery here .... we unfortunately were all trained in high school to think that the electron or photon magically finds its path or that they cancel each other .... not so.  A lot goes on in the EM field before a photon or electron is even emitted.